# Protecting Purchasable Download Links

Tags: php, mysql, security, download

Site sells downloadable media. How would one protect the download links so someone can not copy it and give it to someone?

One time use link? Authentication code in mysql?

Site uses php and mysql.

Comment: Have a php or any other language script to pull the file content for delivery instead of giving the file link directly this way you can password protected and only people who have access to a given file would be able to get it ... that is what the major download websites use theses days I think but that is just a comment not sure if that is the most appropriated way. As for the files just store them in a folder that is not visible by the internet or if it is protect it with a .htaccess file to deny any requests. Since you will bet getting the file content you would still be able to access it.

Comment: You can't. All DRM schemes fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day, after download has been completed, the user could still distribute the downloaded files via other means, so your attempts at protection are somewhat limited.

I would suggest using a link that expires after a certain amount of time.

You can create an hash in php store it against the download, and have a datatime column with the link expiry date. This will give you a unique request url for the file
Then everytime a download attempt is tried, delete any links that have expired, before initiating a download

Comment: Bear in mind that if you choose to expire the content, you may wish to put a support system in place to re-enable the content if the user was not able to succesfully download it in the time alotted.